# Compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar/debug/R.jar (No such file or directory) for Chromium Browser Code build Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, browser, chromium

As per Google Inutructuction for build android Chromium Browser i have followed as below
Step 1 ) https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md

Step 2 ) https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_studio.md

After complete step 2 i have imported gradle build on Android studio and then resolved some duplicate dependancy error,
Now i am facing issue as below,

Execution failed for task ':_all:dexBuilderDebug'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/testing/chromium/src/out/Default/gradle/_all/build/intermediates/compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar/debug/R.jar (No such file or directory)

If anyone have solution about this please share with me.
Thank you.